# Why jQuery click event listener isn't registered on WooCommerce button?

Tags: php, html, jquery, woocommerce, jquery-selectors

I have a WooCommerce based shop, and I am trying to implement some event tracking based on user actions.
I would like to run a custom JS function when the user clicks on the Place order button, which is the final step before paying.

This is the code of the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order">Place order</button>
```

In my script I have this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  // here are some other handlers

  $("#place_order").click(() => {
    alert("click");
  });
});
```

When I log the result of `$("#place_order")`, it seems jQuery can find the element:

```
a.fn.init [button#place_order.button.alt, context: document, selector: "#place_order"]
```

But in the devtools window of google chrome, there's no click handler for this button (under the Event Listeners tab) and the function is not ran.

I have other click events wired up in the very same document.ready function, in a similar way, which works just fine.

Add to cart button:

```
<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="2819" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Add to cart</button>
```

script:

```
$("button[name=add-to-cart]").on("click", () => {
  console.log("product added to cart"); // This works fine and visible under Event Listeners tab
});
```

I've tried using the selector `"button[name=woocommerce_checkout_place_order]"` and with `.on("click")` too.

So what could be the reason my event listener for the place order button is not getting added, or is getting removed?

Is there a way I can check if handlers are removed from the button by other scripts? I'm thinking maybe WooCommerce removes it for some reason.

Comment: Is the woocommerce button being updated by some external js script?

Comment: I'm not sure. Is there a way I can check what other scripts access the element?

Comment: Does woocommerce load any js script?, Also could you first test your code against a custom button, create your own button #myButton and test your code

Comment: Yes, it does. And it has a couple of listeners already on the button. Other buttons work fine.

Comment: Could you try using `<button onclick="myFunc()" />` on woocommerce button , I just want to check what woocommerce script is doing, if function is called than we can have some solution!

Comment: After I add the onclick by hand in the dom editor, it gets called. If I try to add it with jQuery attr(), it is not there and does nothing.

Comment: The woocommerce script must be changing the button removing event handler... , Try executing `$("button[name=add-to-cart]").on("click",function(){})` in setTimeout, so this will act on modified button , or call the event handler after woocommerce has finished running it's script!

Comment: setTimeout didn't help, I moved the handler to the checkout form's submit event, and that works fine. still curious what happens here though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for checkout "place order" **submit** event is **delegated** to the `<form>` by WooCommerce, you will need to delegate the **click** event to the `<form>` too this way:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('form.woocommerce-checkout').on( 'click', "#place_order", function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // Disable submit for testing

        console.log("click");
        alert("click");
    });
});
```

Or the same thing embedded in a function (targeting checkout page):

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_checkout_js_script');
function my_checkout_js_script() {
    // Only on checkout page
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            $('form.woocommerce-checkout').on( 'click', "#place_order", function(event){
                event.preventDefault(); // Disable submit for testing

                console.log("click");
                alert("click");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Now as you will see it works.

Related: [jQuery - Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#:~:text=Event%20delegation%20refers%20to%20the,now%20or%20in%20the%20future.)

Answer (score 0):

as far as I have found, there are custom DOM events triggered by woocommerce that are messing with checkout elements, in order to set up listeners for the elements inside checkout you should wrap your listeners initialization in a function and hook the function both on **init_checkout** and **updated_checkout** events (for some reason found it working only with jQuery .on method).

Example:

```
function initListeners(){

  var btn = document.querySelector('#place_order');
  // Guard clause - if element not found exit function 
  if (!btn) return
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('clicked!');
    // Your code
  })
  
}

jQuery('body').on('init_checkout', initListeners);
jQuery('body').on('updated_checkout', initListeners);
```

A more direct answer to is that above mentioned events strip all listeners from the elements within checkout or just clones them, either way you need to re-hook your listeners after each of them.